# Administrator user getting locked out when adding products

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, j2store

We have a Joomla 3.8.10 website for a client with J2Store 3.3.1, hosted on one of our servers. When our client uses the administrator control panel to add several new products or make several edits, they are kicked out of the administrator backend and then see a "404 Category not found" error when they go to domain.com/administrator. Eventually they can log back in, but they need to wait a long time. We have circumvented this problem by migrating the site to a local server on our client's computer, where they do not encounter the issue, and then migrate it back when they are done making changes.

This is far from ideal, since migrations can be time-consuming. It would be better if the client could just use Joomla and J2Store as intended.

I would like to stop them from getting locked out, but the problem is so vague I'm not sure where to start looking. This issue is not happening on any of our other sites, as far as I know. Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: May I ask why Joomla is not updated to 3.9.4 and J2Store to 3.3.7 ? What is the server PHP version?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a copy of the original site having issues and load it into a different a directory on the same hosting account to try and keep the test environment as close as possible to the live site having the issues by making minimal changes,  just enough to avoid conflicting with the live system, i.e. different DB & domain name. I use Akeeba normally to do this.

On the Test copy turn off any Cache plugins you may have active. The cache I think is playing a part in why it takes some time, but eventually clears the issue.

And then turn set Error Reporting to Maximum or Development in the Global Config. Also turn off GZip compression as I find it causes white screen of death when Error Reporting is happening, but that could just be me.

Now try and recreate the problem and see if you have messages to point you in the right direction or report back here.

Terry